# How do I add plugins to my Ionic project?

Tags: cordova, npm, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to add [ionic-native-transitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-native-transitions) to my app by following the instructions outlined on the page. The steps they online:

Bower

```
bower install shprink/ionic-native-transitions
```

Ionic CLI

```
Ionic plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions#0.5.4`
```

Configuration

```
angular.module('yourApp', [
    'ionic-native-transitions'
]);
```

And this is where everything breaks and I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   yourApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   ionic-native-transitions due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'ionic-native-transitions' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Am I missing something somewhere? Even if it's something very obvious e.g. having to add something to my `index.html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this plugin in one of my project and worked perfectly,

Add  **[ionic-native-transitions](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions)** plugin using command,

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions
```

This plugin contains many animation styles(up,flip,slide,fade,drawer etc) for changing view transitions.

Please Refer this [tutorial](http://www.gajotres.net/handling-native-view-animations-with-ionic-framework/)

If you have any doubt.Please let me know?Thanks

Comment: I don't understand? This is exactly what I did

Comment: I have followed this http://www.gajotres.net/handling-native-view-animations-with-ionic-framework/

Comment: Is that absolutely necessary? And if so, why? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: There’s nothing to inject, nothing to initialize for that plugin

Comment: We are overriding default transitions

Comment: I've finally gotten to a stage where it's looking promising, however I'm getting this in my console output: "nativepagetransitions is disabled or nativepagetransitions plugin is not present"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95655/discussion-between-muhsin-and-dean-gibson).

Answer (score 1):

Hi I got exactly the same problem, for some reasons...
1/ I've installed the lib in my project with bower install shprink/ionic-native-transitions --save
2/ Included in my index.html file
3/ Included the require in my routes.js file
4/ Did a cordova plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions

But at the end I got: nativepagetransitions is disabled or nativepagetransitions plugin is not present

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the script to your `index.html` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-ionic-native-transitions.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I added the following: <script src="../plugins/com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions/www/NativePageTransitions.js"></script> And I'm still getting the same error

Comment: **native-transitions.min.js** must be included in index html for it to work.

Comment: There's no such file, where do I find that file? Have you looked at the plugin's directory structure and file names?

Comment: Search in plugins folder. Still not found, Download it from https://github.com/shprink/ionic-native-transitions/tree/develop/dist

Comment: I've finally gotten to a stage where it's looking promising, however I'm getting this in my console output: "nativepagetransitions is disabled or nativepagetransitions plugin is not present"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's very important to know if you are using a scaffolding tool (I use the generator-ionic-gulp). Recently they changed "the way" of the compiling process, see this link (point 2).
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-ionic-gulp#development-mode

Previously the export of the final vendor.js file (with all the dependencies) came from vendor.json and now it came from bower.json. So in order to work properly you must to update that file :)